# Building Kernel from a custom .config with Buildroot

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, kernel, config, buildroot

I'm trying to generate a custom image for raspberrypi 3 with the usage of buildroot. I have a custom `.config` for Buildroot options where I give the path to `BR2_KERNEL_CUSTOM_CONFIG_FILE` which is located in /boards/raspberrypi3/linux.config

But in the patching stage of the build I find the following error:

```
for f in boards/raspberrypi3/.config ; do
    if [ ! -f "${f}" ]; then
        printf "Kconfig fragment '%s' for '%s' does not exist\n" "${f}" "linux";
        exit 1;
    fi;
done
```

Kconfig fragment

```
'boards/raspberrypi3/linux.config' for 'linux' does not exist
linux/linux.mk:555: recipe for target 'boards/raspberrypi3/.config' failed
```

When I only use the `.config` of buildroot without any path to a custom Linux Kernel config (using the default kernel in menuconfig) everything builds fine.

Comment: Please separate code/error and plain text, refer: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 1):

What is the correct file name for your linux configuration file? You mention that you point BR2_KERNEL_CUSTOM_CONFIG_FILE to /boards/raspberrypi3/linux.config (presumably without the leading slash), but your output snippet shows boards/raspberrypi3/.config?

The upstream location for raspberrypi 3 files is under board/raspberrypi3 (notice BOARD not BOARDS). Please double check

Comment: Hello Peter, thank you for answer. 
The mistake was really the "Boards" instead of "Board" in the PATH.
This stage of the built went fine but the problem now is with the "bcm2710-rpi-b-plus.dtb" which isn't compatible with any kernel repo version i downloaded so far.
There is always the possitibility to copy the .dtb manually to the folder but i'd like to avoid that. 
Any sugestion?

Comment: bcm2710-rpi-b-plus.dtb? Don't you mean bcm2708-rpi-b-plus.dtb, E.G. the dtb used by the raspberry pi kernel for rpi 0/rpi 1?